# XSLT 1.0 Grouping Dataset including distinct elements and 0 or more repeated elements

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, xslt-grouping

I am trying to write some XSLT that groups the XML data based on certain keyed fields. These fields include some static fields as well as the potential of additional fields.

Data Example:

```
<ReportResult>
  <ReportHeader>
    <Header>Device Serial #</Header>
    <Header>Device Type</Header>
    <Header>Site ID</Header>
    <Header>Site Name</Header>
    <Header>Operation</Header>
    <Header>Option1</Header>
    <Header>Option 4</Header>
  </ReportHeader>
  <ReportData>
    <DataEntity>
      <kbserno>31513766</kbserno>
      <DeviceProductDesc>ExampleProductName</DeviceProductDesc>
      <SiteID>ExampleSiteID</SiteID>
      <SiteName>ExampleSiteName</SiteName>
      <OperationCodeDesc>Open</OperationCodeDesc>
      <KeyholderOption />
      <KeyholderOption />
    </DataEntity>
    <DataEntity>
      <kbserno>31513766</kbserno>
      <DeviceProductDesc>ExampleProductName</DeviceProductDesc>
      <SiteID>ExampleSiteID</SiteID>
      <SiteName>ExampleSiteName</SiteName>
      <OperationCodeDesc>Open</OperationCodeDesc>
      <KeyholderOption />
      <KeyholderOption />
    </DataEntity>
  </ReportData>
</ReportResult>
```

As it stands, I have code that groups based on the `kbserno`, `SiteID`, and `OperationCodeDesc`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//DataEntity[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyActivitySummary', concat(kbserno,'+',SiteID,'+',OperationCodeDesc))[1])]">
                
              <xsl:variable name="lngKbserno"><xsl:value-of select="kbserno" /></xsl:variable>
              <xsl:variable name="lngSite"><xsl:value-of select="SiteID" /></xsl:variable>
              <xsl:variable name="lngOperation"><xsl:value-of select="OperationCodeDesc" /></xsl:variable>
                
                
               <!-- Select all the entries that belong to that group -->
               <!--Create template to create select statement below dynamically based on groupingheaders-->
               <xsl:variable name="GroupList" select="//DataEntity[kbserno=$lngKbserno and 
                                                                OperationCodeDesc=$lngOperation and
                                                                  SiteID=$lngSite]" />
               <xsl:for-each select="$GroupList[1]/*">
                 <!-- Do stuff to the grouping -->
               </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Basically, I need to add it such that when KeyholderOption tags are present in the date (as in the data given), the date is additionally grouped on the first KeyholderOption present in each data entity, the second KeyholderOption present, etc.

Additionally, the values in these KeyholderOption entities can be NULL (as shown). However, all entities will have the same number of these entries (ie if an entity has 2 KeyholderOptions, then all entities will have 2).

I have just tried adding KeyholderOption to the key in the code above, but that just results in none of the data being output properly.

Comment: Is the number (or the maximum number) of `KeyholderOption`s known in advance?

Comment: XSLT 3 has the concept of "composite" keys for both `xsl:key` and `for-each-group group-by` where you could use e.g. `use="kbserno, SiteID, OperationCodeDesc, KeyholderOption"` or `group-by="kbserno, SiteID, OperationCodeDesc, KeyholderOption"` to deal with an unknown number of `KeyHolderOption`s. In XSLT 1 you could use XSLT to generate XSLT from your sample in a first step, ensuring that the key declaration and use inserts the existing number of `KeyHolderOption`s and then you could run the generated XSLT. That, however, requires use of a host language like Java or perhaps XProc.

Comment: Can you do more than one transformation?  In the first transformation you could add a <key> element to <DataEntity>.  In the second transformation you can use <key> to do normal Muenchian method grouping.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, the max number is known.

Comment: @Bluewood66 Yes, I believe I can do more than one transformation.  So would that look like an XSLT that outputs XML like the original but with a `<ReportKeys>` section under the `<ReportResult>` section filled with the different element names used for the keys? So, for the example data above the section would look like: 
`<ReportResult><ReportKeys><Key>kbserno</Key><Key>SiteID</Key><Key>OperationCodeDesc</Key><Key>KeyholderOption</Key></ReportKeys>...`

Or would that be multiple `<Key>` tags with KeyholderOption?

Comment: I am still confused. Do you want to group by the concatenated value of all `KeyholderOption`s? Or do you want to group by the first `KeyholderOption` and within each group create subgroups by the 2nd `KeyholderOption`, etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the first transform to add the  element.  Then you can use the Muenchian grouping method for the second transform and get rid of the key, if needed.  Play with the key to get it how you want it.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DataEntity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>

    <xsl:element name="key">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(kbserno, '^^')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(SiteID, '^^')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(OperationCodeDesc, '^^')"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="KeyholderOption">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '^^')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
    
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```